# Selenium webdriver element not found in modal pop-up

Tags: selenium-webdriver

html:

```
button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="document.getElementById('formChangePIN').submit();">Submit</button
```

code:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[class='btn btn-primary']"))).click();
```

while this code works in runtime

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\\\"blockCardModal\\\"]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]"))).click();
```

Comment: Could you try using xpath for the first one? So: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary']"))).click();

Comment: try this `By.cssSelector("#blockCardModal button[class='btn btn-primary']"))`

Comment: all codes suggested now works! thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try window handles to switch between the windows and perform the click action

or use Action driver to click

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator)
actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```